# Looking for IE/z-index workaround for elements in different parents with same classname

Tags: internet-explorer-7, z-index

I know about IE7's bug regarding z-index and how you can add a higher z-index to the parent of the element that you want to appear above its parent's siblings. But I have several list items of the same classname (each list item and its children have the same DOM structure), and each LI has a child element that must appear above the next list item in the DOM. For reasons I won't go into, I cannot place an unique classname or ID on each LI.

In IE7 the popdown is below the next LI. Any ideas given that I can't target the parent LI with a higher z-index? Thanks.

Example screenshot here: http://tinypic.com/r/2m5ud/6